# how to decrypt aes in powershell that was encrypted via .net

Tags: powershell, encryption

i am not an encryption expert, but i was able to use the following code to encrypt string in .net application , so i take "mystring" which was clear text from .net and encrypt it using CipherUtility

```
string encrypted = CipherUtility.Encrypt<AesManaged>(mystring, "password", "salt");
```

the code for CipherUtility i used from the following link

https://bitlush.com/blog/symmetric-encryption-in-c-sharp

I was able to pass my encrypted string to Python and decrypt it using AES lib/module from Python fine.. Now i am trying to figure out how to pass my encrypted string to Powershell and decrypt this via Powershell using some AES method?

i was looking at this code

https://gist.github.com/ctigeek/2a56648b923d198a6e60

but i could not figure out how to get it to work with just supplying password which is set to "password" and salt which is set to "salt" from my example above??

i tried the decrypt function from the code found at this site but kept running into padding errors
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Script-410ef9df

UPDATE:

here is my .net code that encrypts taken from cipher_utility.cs

```
public static string Encrypt<T>(string value, string password, string salt)
             where T : SymmetricAlgorithm, new()
        {
            DeriveBytes rgb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(salt));

            SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = new T();

            byte[] rgbKey = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.KeySize >> 3);
            byte[] rgbIV = rgb.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize >> 3);
            string test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rgbKey);

            ICryptoTransform transform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey, rgbIV);

            using (MemoryStream buffer = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream stream = new CryptoStream(buffer, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode))
                    {
                        writer.Write(value);
                    }
                }

                return Convert.ToBase64String(buffer.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

then i am taking the code from the gallery.technet.microsoft post from above and changing it to what i think it should be :) based on my .net code

```
function Decrypt-String($Encrypted, $salt="salt", $init="password")
{
    # If the value in the Encrypted is a string, convert it to Base64
    if($Encrypted -is [string]){
        $Encrypted = [Convert]::FromBase64String($Encrypted)
       }


    # Create a COM Object for RijndaelManaged Cryptography
    $r = new-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged

    # Convert the Passphrase to UTF8 Bytes
    #$pass = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Passphrase)

    # Convert the Salt to UTF Bytes
    $salt = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($salt)

    # Create the Encryption Key using the passphrase, salt and SHA1 algorithm at 256 bits
    $r.Key = (new-Object Security.Cryptography.PasswordDeriveBytes $init, $salt, "SHA1", 5).GetBytes(32) #256/8

    # Create the Intersecting Vector Cryptology Hash with the init
    $r.IV = (new-Object Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed).ComputeHash( [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($init) )[0..15]

    # Create a new Decryptor
    $d = $r.CreateDecryptor()

    # Create a New memory stream with the encrypted value.
    $ms = new-Object IO.MemoryStream @(,$Encrypted)

    # Read the new memory stream and read it in the cryptology stream
    $cs = new-Object Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream $ms,$d,"Read"

    # Read the new decrypted stream
    $sr = new-Object IO.StreamReader $cs

    # Return from the function the stream
    Write-Output $sr.ReadToEnd()

    # Stops the stream    
    $sr.Close()

    # Stops the crypology stream
    $cs.Close()

    # Stops the memory stream
    $ms.Close()

    # Clears the RijndaelManaged Cryptology IV and Key
    $r.Clear()

}
```

i am getting the following padding error

```
Exception calling "Close" with "0" argument(s): "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed."
At C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp\67499731-a8a3-4871-a807-f11ba86a26bf.ps1:33 char:5
+     $sr.Close()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CryptographicException
```

so my end goal is to decrypt in powershell what i am encrypted in .net using AES.

Comment: "... kept running into padding errors" please post the full error and the code that produced it

Comment: hi, sorry i am late here i got sided tracked on other projects. i added my .net code i am using to encrypt in AES. again i can decrypt this in python fine, i'm just not sure how to do it in powershell and running into issues. i added the pshell error i get, i did change the pshell decrypt code from the original source a bit, as you can see in my .net code i am only using a password and a salt. the pshell original decrypt code from the link above, used some additional password ? so i removed that.